# Using the Z-transform properties with the inverse z transform by MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab

I am using the [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) properties with the inverse Z-transform by MATLAB.

I cannot find a function that would apply the Z-tranform properties to convert the result by `residuez` to the time domain. Here is the image of question,

[image]

### Edit

I can't believe such a powerful math language does not have functions to convert using the Z-transform table and Laplace transform tables.

Comment: @user287745: MATLAB at its core is a numerical math tool. There is a 'Symbolic Math Toolbox' as well. You might consider using Mathematica for symbolic math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all you need in *[Partial Fraction Expansion](http://www.ws.binghamton.edu/fowler/fowler%20personal%20page/EE301_files/Notes_29b%20Sect%208-3%20Partial%20Fraction%20Expansion.pdf)* (PDF document).

**EDIT:**
One possible source for a [Table of Laplace and Z Transforms](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/LPSA/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html).

Comment: yup it answered as: " and then using the Laplace Transform Table for each of the two terms in the expansion we get:"